# why long COOKIE_TIMEOUT = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 return negative?

Tags: java, long-integer

```
final long COOKIE_TIMEOUT = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
```

Output: -1702967296

Someone told me to put L after 1000 & it works

```
final long COOKIE_TIMEOUT = 1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
```

Output: 2592000000

Why does that happen?

Comment: may be integer overflow...??

Comment: I tested in eClipse & it printed out negative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Integer overflow, put 1000L, this will force long conversion

**UPDATE**
Slightly longer explanation:

If you just do 1000*10 for example, java will see them as integers.
In your original code, you were doing an integer calculation which overflowed, then cast the overflowed value to long.

However if you put L after the first number, java will see them as longs (left-most operand defines the granularity) and you won't get an overflow.

As another example take this code:

```
double a = 5 / 2;
double b = 5d / 2;

System.out.println(a + " != " + b);
```

This will print out:

```
2.0 != 2.5
```

Why? When calculating a, java sees 5 and 2 as integers and does an integer division, then casts the result to a double. When calculating b you tell java that 5 is actually a double at which point it performs a double division.

Answer (score 3):

Although `COOKIE_TIMEOUT` is `long` the right-hand expression consists of integers, so its type is `int`. The result is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` that causes overflow. When at least one operand in your expression belongs to higher type (e.g. `long`) whole expression becomes `long` and  overflow does not happen.

This is what you did in your second example when you added `L` modifier after one of the numeric constants. This constant became `long`, so the expression became `long` too.

Answer (score 3):

This behavior is due to the *type* of the expression selected by the Java compiler. In this case it looks something like so:

```
int  * int  -> int (which overflows here during the multiplication)
long * long -> long
long * int  = long * long (by promotion) -> long
int  * long = long (by promotion) * long -> long
```

This promotion happens pretty much universally for the math operators: the widest/largest type is used, with the smaller type being promoted and the `x op x -> x` expression being applied (classically, integer vs. floating division).

The `L` results in a long value and thus the multiplication selected is `long * long (by promotion) -> long`, which is free from the immediate overflow discovered. The `long` expression result type propagates to all the other multiplications.

Bonus points: it would still fail (overflow) if written as `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 1L`, *why?*

Answer (score 2):

It is greatter than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` which is `2147483647`

By default all numeric litaral are considered as `Integer`. to define a `Long` numeric value you have to add `L` or 'l' with the number.

Comment: +1, `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is 2147483647.

Comment: I was scared after reading `Long.MAX_VALUE` earlier :p ;)

Comment: heheh... dat surprised me even, corrected... thanks sp00m & KisHan

Answer (score 1):

The reason of that behavior is [integer overflow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html).

Your first statement can be understand like this:

`long time = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;`

is the same as

```
int time = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
long timel = time;
```

First you compute the expression, then you assign to long type;

---

When you put suffix `L` to literal you define it as long type.

[**JSL 3.10.1. Integer Literals**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html)

> An integer literal is of type long if it is suffixed with an ASCII
>   letter L or l (ell); otherwise it is of type int (§4.2.1).

`long time = 1000L * ( 60 * 60 * 24 * 30);`

can be written also as

`long time = ((long) 1000) * ( 60 * 60 * 24 * 30);`

More about [Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
It is causing for Integer overflow(Max value upto 2147483647).
```

You can postfix **L** at the end of the any numeric value.

Like `1000L`

**Then it forcely converts into Long type**

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is that the right hand side is evaluated before the assignment to the left hand side. Since you are multiplying several `int`s, the resulting type will be `int`. Then, after evaluating the right hand side, it will see that it is supposed to assign this value to a long, and do the casting automatically.

So you have:

Evaluated right hand side as `int`: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 = `2,592,000,000`.

The maximum value of an `int` is:  `2,147,483,647`.

So you have an overflow, which makes the int negative. This is then assigned to a long, still negative.

When you specify one of the operands on the right hand side to be `long`, then the expression will be evaluated has a `long`, which has a much larger maximum value.

Answer (score 0):

Every number in the formula is an Integer, hence Java will perform all calculations in Integer and store the result temporarily as Integer. However the result exceeds Integer Max range (overflow), so it becomes negative.

1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 = 2592000000 (exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE)

Only when Java needs to assign it to the Long variable Java will cast it into a Long. Since the result is already wrong result (due to overflow) then the Long variable will be assigned with the wrong result.

However if you already declare the 1000 as Long (1000L), then the remaining calculations will be done as Long instead of Integer.